# How to center text inside a li element inside an unordered list

Tags: css, text, html-lists

This list is working great for me but the text within the `<li>` elements is not centering.

The `<li>`s must auto resize to their content.

```css
#nav-menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-bottom: dotted thin #666666;
    border-top: dotted thin #666666;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}

#nav-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
}

#nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: dotted thin #666666;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 0.75em;
}

#nav-menu li a {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">zxczczxczHome</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If the `<li>` elements have an automatic size and are floated to appear next to one another, how can they be centered?

Comment: Also, your example HTML doesn't close the `<li>` tags. Working with valid HTML makes CSS much more predictable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you're assigning unequal `padding` values to the left and right of the `li` (`0.75em` and `2em` respectively) the text *can't be centred* since you're forcing it off-centre with the `padding`.

If you amend the padding to: `padding: 0.5em 1em;` (`0.5em` top and bottom, `1em` left and right) then it can be centred.

```css
#nav-menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../img/menu_bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-bottom: dotted thin #666666;
    border-top: dotted thin #666666;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}

#nav-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
}

#nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: dotted thin #666666;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

#nav-menu li a {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#" title="Home">zxczczxczHome</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gfTH2/1/) of the above.

Comment: David : Thank you so much - I just spotted that! and i was trying to delete my question! heh thank you again!!! god that seams so obvious!

Comment: @Rob: please don't delete questions that merited being asked in the first place. Especially questions that have attracted answers. And, also, you're welcome; glad to have been of help. :)

Comment: So, what property exactly is doing the centering? I think it's clear padding needs to be equal on both sides.

Answer (score 7):

If you want various sizes, then change the right or left padding property to be the same as the other one:

```
padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
```

or

```
padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em;
```

I've fiddled around with it a little: http://jsfiddle.net/Q32hn/
Don't forget to always close your ListItems

Comment: BTW, I also removed the div and moved its styling to the UL