# How to center text in lists?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website footer inspired by the [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/html/default.asp) 4 column footer, however, the text in the `li` tags go off to the right a little (compared to the headings).

**CSS:**

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 100px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.footerFloat {
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 950px) {
  #footer {
    width: 980px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .footerFloat {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<header></header>
<footer>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 1</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 4</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 3</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 4</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOPnI.png) of the problem.

Does anyone know how I could fix this, and centre the text with the headings in the footer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

—ItzJavaCraft

Comment: Can you provide an image of your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center Text inside an li element inside an unordered list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147830/center-text-inside-an-li-element-inside-an-unordered-list)

Comment: You probably just need to zero the padding of your UL list.

Comment: @kabaehr I will add one to the post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the padding which is built into the `ul` by default.

```css
 
      .footerFloat {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
      }
      #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0; /* here---add this */
      }
      .center {
        text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 1</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 4</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 3</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4 class="center">Header 4</h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="center">Line 1</li>
          <li class="center">Line 2</li>
          <li class="center">Line 3</li>
          <li class="center">Line 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```