# Center a ul element in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to center the paragraph and the white blocks under OUR MISSION header [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2kFo.jpg) should be enough, if not, let me know and I can upload the the code here.

in that ul element there is a paragraph and a four li to make 4 photos go across the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- Home Page -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css">
    <script src="js/mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div>
                <ul id="navigation">
                    <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                    <li class="selected">
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu">
                        <a href="events.html">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu">
                        <a href="registration.html">Registration</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body" class="home">
            <div class="header">
                <div>
                    <h1>title 2</h1>
                    <a href="about.html" class="more">Read More</a>
                    <h3>Mission</h3>
                    <ul>
                    <p>I NEED TO CENTER THIS AND THE FOUR PICTURES TO FOLLOW</p>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/homepage-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/homepage-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/homepage-3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/homepage-4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div>
                    <h1>title 3</h1>
                    <p>inser more here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="connect">
                <div>
                    <h1>Check us out on YouTube</h1>
                    <div>
                        <a href="d" class="YouTube">Youtube</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footnote">
                <div>
                    <p>footnote here
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

STYLE SHEET
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
body #page {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top #000000;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 3;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
a:active {
    background: none;
}
img {
    border: none;
}
/*-------------------------------------------FONTS---------------------------------------------*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'audiowide-regular-webfont';
    src: url('../fonts/audiowide-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/audiowide-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/audiowide-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/audiowide-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
/*----------------------------------------header-styles---------------------------------------*/
#header {
    background: url(../images/bg-transparent1.png) repeat;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#header div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#header div a.logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 44px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 304px;
}
#header div a img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#header div ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#header div ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#header div ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 59px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 24px;
 *padding: 0 23px; /* Needed for IE8 and old versions */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}
#header div ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #620031;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#header div ul li.selected a {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #a3a3a3;
}
#header div ul li.menu {
    position: relative;
}
#header div ul li.menu ul {
    display: block;
    left: -99999px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 142px;
    z-index: 50;
}
#header div ul li.menu:hover ul.primary {
    left: 31px;
}
#header div ul li.menu ul.primary.selected {
    left: 31px;
}
#header div ul li.menu:hover ul.secondary {
    left: -20px;
}
#header div ul li.menu ul.secondary.selected {
    left: -20px;
}
#header div ul li.menu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#header div ul li.menu ul li a {
    background-color: #620031;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}
#header div ul li.menu ul.primary.selected li a, #header div ul li.menu ul.secondary.selected li a {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #a3a3a3;
}
/*----------------------------------------body-home-styles---------------------------------------*/
#body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 808px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#body.home {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1308px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#body.home .header {
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#body.home .header div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#body.home .header div h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: audiowide-regular-webfont;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0 15px;
    padding: 0 38px 0 399px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 503px;
    z-index: 60;
}
#body.home .header div h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin: 0 0 36px;
    padding: 0 146px 0 506px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 288px;
    z-index: 60;
}
#body.home .header div a.more {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #a3a3a3;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 49px;
    line-height: 49px;
    margin: 0 150px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    left: 110px;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 55;
}
#body.home .header div a.more:hover {
    background-color: #ab000b;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#body.home .header div h3 {
    background: url("../images/bg-transparent1.png") repeat;
    color: #A3A3A3;
    float: left;
    font-family: audiowide-regular-webfont;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin: 50px 0 0;
 *margin: 102px 0 0;/* Needed for IE8 and old versions */
    min-height: 27px;
    padding: 15px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 940px;
}
#body.home .header div ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 -6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#body.home .header div ul li:first-child {
    padding: 0;
}
#body.home .header div ul li {
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#body.home .header div ul li a {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
    height: 156px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 235px;
}
#body.home .header div ul li a img {
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);/* Needed for IE8 and old versions */
    opacity: 1.0;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
#body.home .header div ul li a img:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);/* Needed for IE8 and old versions */
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#body.home .body {
    background-color: #ef1717;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 168px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#body.home .body div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 940px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 31px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Include your code please.

Comment: And a `p` can't be a direct child of a `ul`. Fix that, too, please.

Comment: what is the easiest way to upload the code? I dont have a github usually I copy and past but there is too much this time to just do that

Comment: try http://codepen.io/

Comment: @train55255 there should not be too much code. You don't need to include your entire website. Read about how to create a [mcve]. And don't link to codepen or jsfiddle when you can include your code in the post on StackOverflow. Those links may not always be around, and that won't help others when they find your post a year from now and the jsfiddle/codepen link has changed. You can read about that here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would recommend looking into [css-tricks Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147830/how-to-center-text-inside-a-li-element-inside-an-unordered-list Here try this

Comment: This is why I am not sure what to upload because I am not a Web Dev and I  just build on a template so I rly don't know a whole lot I just see stuff from chromes inspect element and try to move it around

Comment: You have modified everything quite a bit introducing a few irrelevant divs. I think it will be easier if you can provide a picture of what you want to achieve (the current one is not clear) and the original codebase.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

probably it will work.

Comment: so which ul specifically? Cause I am not rly famliar with css and html